# How to check if my IOS App support IOS 3+? And something about anonymous function

Tags: objective-c, ios, anonymous-function

I'm new to IOS development, sometimes I use a function but ignore its Doc.
So, I may use some functions are only supported on IOS 4 or even IOS 5, but I want to support IOS 3+.

Does it has any way to check if my app support IOS 3+? 
I don't want to check line by line, thx.

And BTW, anonymous function like void (^ funcName)(NSString *) is objective-c feature, right? So it is supported on all IOS version, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your 'Deployment Target' to 3.x to see if any methods you're using aren't supported on that version.

That however is **not** a substitute for testing on 3.x; so either find a 3.x device or drop support for that version. Also, blocks (the 'anonymous function' you describe) are only available on iOS 4 and above.

If you want to write different sets of code for different version targets, you can use preprocessor directives:

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 50000
    ... 5.x code here ...
#elif __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000
    ... 4.x code here ...
#else
    ... 3.x code here ...
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Try running your app on a device running 3.x

by anonymous functions do you mean blocks like:

```
[self performSomeBlock:^(NSString *smth) {
    NSLog(@"%@", smth);
}];
```

or do you mean just c like definitions (its late so i forgot the legit name)

```
void doSomething(void *(*func)(NSString *)) {
...
}
```

Comment: anonymous functions I mean is the first one you mention, so it is supported on all IOS versions, right?